# how to get the position of an element in inactive tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to get the position of an element such as div in an inactive tab using jquery or javascript?I am only able to get the position from the active tab. Please someone help me.

Comment: share your code too in your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery-UI tabs then unfortunately it isn't possible. jQuery-UI hides the inactive *tab* applying the CSS property `display: none`.  This means the *tab* (the `div`) and it's contents take up no space and therefore have no position.

Comment: thank you for you comments. I actually solved it by making display:block to those tab and display: none after getting the position.